# php faker and laravel factorties unique date for each new row

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

I am wanting to create 24 rows in a database table each row needs a unique date in it, between the 1/12/2019 (1st December) & 24/12/2019 (24 December) inlcusive.

I using factories to create rows of data when I am running my tests, my factory currently runs looks like this,

```
$factory->define(Quiz::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'date_playable' => $faker->dateTimeInInterval('2019-12-01', '+ 1 day', 'Europe/London')
];
```

});

In my tests I do the following,

```
$quizes = factory('App\Quiz', 24)->create();
```

However when I query the DB the rows in the quiz table the date_playable are all unique in that all have unique time as part of the DATETIME, but the date is always 2019-12-01.

How can I make sure each row has a `date_playable` that increments from the last on, OR has a unique day in it's DATETIME string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better create an ordinary factory.

**Factory**

```php
$factory->define(Quiz::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'date_playable' => $faker->dateTime(),
    ];
});
```

In the test create a date range as you want, and call factory for those each date.

**Test**

```php
$dates = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-12-01', '2019-12-12');

$dates->forEach(function($date) {
    factory(Quiz::class)->create([
        'date_playable' => $date->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);
});
```